# Remove mistyped parameters I entered with "ALTER SYSTEM SET"

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-11

I was entering a bunch of `ALTER SYSTEM SET` commands and one of them I mistyped. Now I keep getting:

> unrecognized configuration parameter

How can I remove that configuration parameter?

I am using **PostgreSQL 11** and was using **psql** when I entered those set commands so it is NOT in the `PostgreSQL.conf` file.

Answer (score 3):

Settings defined through `alter system` are stored in the file `postgresql.auto.conf`.

You can simply remove the entry from that file - but you **have** to shut down Postgres before you do that.

Answer (score 2):

No need to shut down the server just to reset configuration parameters set with `ALTER SYSTEM SET`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html)

> Setting a parameter to `DEFAULT`, or using the `RESET` variant, removes that configuration entry from the `postgresql.auto.conf` file.

This would do the job - for valid configuration parameters:

```
ALTER SYSTEM RESET valid_config_param;
```

**However**, Postgres 11 does not allow invalid configuration parameters with `ALTER SYSTEM SET` to begin with. The error message you report is probably triggered by an attempt to *set* the invalid parameter yet again:

> ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "invalid_config_param"

Maybe a script containing an invalid command?